How to get the address of a struct element in another field of same structure in rust?
struct CirBuffer {
    buf: [u8; 256],
    lowest_mem_addr: *const u8,
    highest_mem_addr: *const u8,
    is_empty: bool,
    is_full: bool,
}

The struct item lowest_mem_addr is to hold the address of buf[0].
impl CirBuffer {
fn create () -> Self{
    CirBuffer {
        buf: [0;256],
        lowest_mem_addr: &(*self).buf[0],=> How to get the address of buf[0] here ?
        highest_mem_addr: &self.buf[255],


In short - this won't work, for the same reason self-referencing structs don't work.
Any type in Rust is assumed to be trivially movable - that is, you always can call memcpy on the underlying bytes, forget about the original and use the copy as if it was the original, and everything should work as-is. But with your type, if you ever expect your pointers to be valid (and why wouldn't you, if you're creating them?), it would break - pointers will still point to the old position, which is now dangling.
There are several different ways to fix this, depending on what you want:

Just use VecDeque. It would be good enough for many practical cases.
Put the buffer on the heap, as Box<[u8; 256]>. In this case, you must be careful not to move this buffer out of the box - in particular, you must never expose a mutable reference to buf, since caller might then simply mem::swap it. There might be another considerations - I'm not an expert with unsafe code, better have a review from more experienced programmers.
Use indices instead of pointers. You might want to store them as u8 and use buf[idx as usize], since in this case bound checks will be optimized away - check "Show Assembly" in this playground.


(d) Use Pin - but this is a mess. Using indices is the best solution.

@ChayimFriedman: I don't think indexing inside addr_of_mut!((*this_ptr).buf[0]) is safe, as the macro documentation states "Note that Deref/Index coercions (and their mutable counterparts) are applied inside addr_of_mut! like everywhere else, in which case a reference is created to call Deref::deref or Index::index, respectively.".

@eggyal Indeed, but array (and slice) indexing is an intrinsic and does not go via Index.

@ChayimFriedman: Is that guaranteed or an implementation detail?  Must we not, semantically, still understand a reference to be created there?

@eggyal To be honest, I'm not sure. I also didn't put a lot of effort into this code: it was more like a demonstration.
